# Message "debian/rules: no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, debian, cross-compiling

I'm a beginner at Debian, and GNU/linux in general and I was following a tutorial to create a cross compiler, when I stumbled upon the message

/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 178: /debian/rules/: No such file or directory

when running the following command

TARGET="alpha-dec-osf4" fakeroot debian/rules binary-cross

or even

fakeroot /debian/rules/ clean

I'm trying to find a manual or guide to learn about debian/rules, but I even have problems finding something for beginners.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?  I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy)

Thank you very much in advance

EDIT: I tried these commands to compile a binutils 2.17, in order to make a cross compiler that would output Alpha OSF/1 binaries on x86 systems. I downloaded binutils from the GNU webpage, so perhaps this was my main mistake, as @Sigi explained that it should be a debian package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not use `/debian/rules`, but instead `debian/rules` (note the missing slash at the beginning).  If you start a path to a file with a slash (`/`), the system will start the search in the root directory of your filesystem (this is the top-most directory on any Unix system).  On the other hand, if your path does *not* begin with a slash, the search will always be relative to your current directory.  The latter is what applies to invoking `debian/rules`.

The command is supposed to be executed inside an extracted Debian source package.  Check if `ls debian/rules` will list a file, otherwise you are in the wrong directory.

Regarding a guide for beginners or anything: Debian package building, let alone the creating or modification of Debian packages is decidedly **not** a beginner's topic.  You should first get a solid foundational knowledge in Linux administration before getting your hands dirty in that area.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Sigi. I tried the command without the first slash and the same message appears. I then tried ls debian/rules and the message "ls: cannot access debian/rules: No such file or directory".

The directory i'm working on is the extracted package of a binutils version I'm trying to compile (version 2.17). I placed this directory in Home. I don't know if I have to do something else. Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly did you download and then extract the binutils package?  It does not seem to be a Debian source package (otherwise it would contain a file `debian/rules`, which is a part of *all* Debian source packages).  Please edit the question with more information.

Comment: I downloaded the package from the GNU website. I'll try with another package. Thank you very much!

Comment: @StickBoy The package from the GNU website is not a Debian source package.  In order to retrieve the Debian source package, you have to use `apt-get source <package>`, for example `apt-get source binutils`, which will download that source package and extract it.  That's what you want to work with.